# rails 3 associations with join table query using active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have three models which are User, Domain and Association. My user model is populated from devise. My Domain model consists of "People's interests such as - running, biking etc". My association table links a user_id to a domain_id and stores it as a record. When I add a domain it automatically populates the user sign up form with domain's (in which a user can pick e.g. I like running).

My Query is.. What active record query could I use to pull user's with the similar interests e.g. running, with the currently logged on user. So if a user called Tom was logged in and had select domain interests of running and biking (linked to), how could I pull back a database object with other users that had the similar domain's (interests)

So basically if Tom, Paul and Steph were users, but Tom and Paul selected the same domain's and Steph selected different ones, what would be the Query code to do this? Hope this is enough information.

Comment: refer http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do something like this:

```
User.joins(:domains).where("domains.id IN (?)", current_user.domains.pluck(:domain_id))
```

`current_user.domains.pluck(:domain_id)` collects all the domain ids that the current_user has selected.  Pluck is only in rails 3.2, if you're using an earlier version, you'll have to use collect instead.

Then the first part of the query selects the users who also have that domain as one of their interests.

You should look at the rails guide as Bongs suggests
 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: This works perfect! Thank you. After passing that query string in via my controller, how could I display the particular domain name itself? From within my model which is passed to the view?? User.domain.name doesnt seem to work? I need to be able to store an array so that I can extract the name of the particular domain you see which is passed to my view

Comment: And I remember you, we went for a pint! I used to work at NTI Studio

Comment: Hi Tom - I've just got a proper job at yoomee.com, so I'll be moving on from the nti. Nice to see you on here!

Comment: Brilliant, sounds good. I'll give that a go tonight when I get in. Cheers for the help